# Настройка включения библиотек для cxxtest

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

Я хочу тестировать свой код. С гидом по cxx я уже ознакомился, но там очень мало посвящено теме include. У меня есть класс testWriter и в нем около 5 методов которые тестируют класс writer. Я подключил класс writer к классу testWriter оформил все по стардартам, запустил команду cxxtestgen она отработала, но на этапе компиляции runner'а выдаётся ошибка, что writer.h не найден. Я смекнул в чем дело и добавил к команде cxxtestgen нужный флаг и все это выглядело так:

```
cxxtestgen --error-printer --include writer.h -o runner.cpp testWriter.h
```

, но ошибка все равно та же. Я перепробовал много разных методов танцев с бубном, но ничего не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Вы ничего не указали - см. [документацию](http://cxxtest.com/guide.html):

```
--include=HEADER      Include file HEADER in the test runner before other
                      headers.
```

, так как Вы проигнорировали формат ('=' отсутствует):

```
--include writer.h
```

Comment: Вы очень интересно подметили . Но в создаваемом файле runner.cpp как раз таки можно посмотреть что там внутри и выходит так что там есть строчка include <write.hr> ,однако ,я нашел решение . Нужно заменить в самом файле эту же строку на "writer.h" и проблемы уходят.

Comment: @РодионЯкутович, рад, если был Вам полезен.